# Laravel 4 clone via Pagoda Box timing out

Tags: php, git, laravel, pagoda-box

I have recently created a project via Pagoda Box in which contains a single Laravel 4 project that cannot render the default index page.

This project can be successfully cloned via Git. Needed dependencies were installed via `composite install`. Lastly, and most importantly, I have set my environment variable in `Boxfile` to a local machine parameter:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('snippets.dev'),                             
));
```

I have carried out all the necessities required to get a working copy on my local system, however, none work. I have followed several examples here and even a video posted recently that walked through the process. Still, I have yet to fix this issue. Above all, the main connection exception I am receiving from Laravel is:

```
Predis \ Connection \ ConnectionException
Connection timed out [tcp://tunnel.pagodabox.com:6379]
```

Detective work suggest this has to do with Pagoda and Redis. The solution to this issue was of course to set a local enviroment variable. I have and still, no success. If anyone has any suggestions, I am happy to test them out.

OS: Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: @AnthonySterling how would I check? And would this really be the case for a timeout?

Comment: Yes - because there isn't a service listening on that port at that address. I don't use Pagodabox, but tunnel.pagodabox.com seems odd to me. I'd check that that is the correct address to be using, and that Redis is available. This should help: http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/articles/415164-redis

Comment: @AnthonySterling Thank you for the suggestion. I have included the cache1 name and redis option in my Boxfile. I also made sure that I had a cache device up and running on Pagoda. It's odd that this hosting is giving me such issues.

Answer (score 1):

I found your question because I am having the same issue with a new Laravel 4 project. What may be a clue is I had no difficulty using redis on pagodabox on a previous project, so when looking for the differences, the working project continues to run Laravel 3.2.3 with an older PHP, and did not use composer to git and install all the dependent components. Looking at differences between the database.config, they both use 'host' => 'tunnel.pagodabox.com', 'port' => 6379, but the old Laravel uses regis and the new Laravel uses predis. Looking at the differences between boxfiles, I see the old declared /storage/database under shared_writable_dirs but I'd hope for a better error message than "timed out". Still, worth a try. I'll let you know if this fixes it. Let me know if you find a solution.

No, adding database as writable dir did nothing.

OK, it's working. Try adding a redis cache using your pagodabox admin panel. Worked for me. I see my old project has one too; I forgot about this.